# Copying Code or Data from SE When In a Slider Box

Tags: support

Sometimes code or data in a posted question is in a box with a horizontal slider. Is there some way to select all of the data and copy it to put in a Mathematica notebook? I can only select what is displayed and then material outside the box, but never all the material within the box.

Comment: Dragging selection outside code block will force it to scroll. But I'm also interested in neat solution.

Comment: You can also use [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3537/5) to import all of the code in a post using the URL from the "share" link

Comment: @ Kuba Dragging outside the code block in IE did not work for me. It ended up selecting material outside the code block. The triple click did work.

Answer (score 6):

For all those who use *browser user scripts*: there is an [Select Code Block Button Script](https://stackapps.com/q/2553/14269) which I have tweaked further to work for our site and Chrome. You can find my answer here

- [halirutan's hack for selecting code blocks](https://stackapps.com/a/3766/14269)

The script is really easy to use. As soon as you move the mouse over a code block, a *Select* button appears which when clicked selects all the text in the code block; with or without scroll bars.

> [image]

Comment: [I get some weird interaction on Firefox](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mok61.png)

Comment: @belisarius Hm, this is very unfortunate. I always thought the script was made *for* Firefox. Can you try the original script and change the header appropriately? You can just copy my header, so that it is working on on M.SE.

Comment: Yep, the original one seems to work better with Firefox (v23.0). I haven't tested it extensively, but at least the edit window buttons are there

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox you can triple-click to select a full line, then while *still holding the mouse button* drag up or down to select additional lines.

Here is some junk code to test it on:

```
#/.(##&[15#->FizzBuzz,3#->Fizz,5#->Buzz]&)/@#&@Range@100 #//.(##&[15#->{3#,5#},3#->Fizz,5#->Buzz]&)/@#&@Range@100
foo[x_, y_, z_, opts1 : OptionsPattern[], z : {opts2 : OptionsPattern[]} : {}] :=  Grid[{{Plot[Sin[x a], {a, y, z}, opts1], Plot[Cos[x a], {a, y, z}, opts2]}}]
f4[s_, m_] := s[[#]] & /@ SparseArray[Permutations[1 ~Table~ {m} ~PadRight~ Length[s]]]["AdjacencyLists"]
```

Comment: OK, many thanks. That also works for Internet Explorer.